# magento 2 category url with timestamp

Tags: magento2.3, url

how to remove the timestamp in magento 2 category page url when clicking next page
When I enter a category page and click page 2, page 3, and so on, my category URL is like this: mysite.com/categoryA.html?*=1667391802008&p=5,  there is a timestamp in my URL.
When I enter first this category A, the URL looks good like this:  mysite.com/categoryA.html
when I click page 2, the URL turns like this:  mysite.com/categoryA.html?*=1667391802011&p=2,  the timestamp appear.
Could someone help me? How to remove the timestamp please?
Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Magento doesn't add any timestamp in the pagination url, This might have happened due to any custom module that you have added to your project. Check if this timestamp is added in the server side or from the client side and then narrow down to any suspected module then disable it and check.